# Setting binary data in Phalcon Response

Tags: php, http, rest, response, phalcon

I have a **BLOB** field (jpeg image) in my DB, and I want to reply a Phalcon Request (Accept: image/jpeg) with this data.

My model class is called "Produto" and the BLOB field is "imagem" (in base64). Since **$p** is an object of type "Produto", it has a field called "imagem", I tried to send the binary data in the response body, without success.

I already set:

```
$this->response->setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
$this->response->setContent(base64_decode($produto->imagem));
```

Comment: You can reply to your own question with the answer and mark it that as the answer for others to find :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK to send BLOB data in message body. My problem was the REST Client I was using.

In curl, the command was:

```
curl -X GET <url> -H "Accept: image/jpeg" -o "image.jpeg"
```

And I get the file without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->response->setContentType('image/jpeg');
$this->response->setContent(base64_decode($produto->imagem));
return $this->response;

/* Second way
$this->response->send();
exit;
*/

/* Don't use it directly
return;
*/
```